# How to change the sgl using multiple conditions

Tags: mysql

I need to change the column Rank cluster based on the column rank

This is the query I am using, but I returns me the "TOP10" only for the rank =1 and all the other values get "TOP30"

```
update se.se_source_data 
set Rank_Cluster = (case ranking  when ranking <= 11 then 'Top10' 
                    when ranking <= 20 then 'TOP20'
                    else 'TOP30+' end)
```

Comment: case ranking  - remove ranking.and review https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html

Comment: @P.Salmon OP uses CASE operator, not CASE statement.

Comment: @akina - indeed so.more like an incorrect hybrid.

Answer (score 1):

If you need  search_condition eg:  `ranking <= 11` then  you should use this syntax

```
update se.se_source_data 
set Rank_Cluster = (case  
                   when ranking <= 11 then 'Top10' 
                    when   ranking <= 20 then 'TOP20'
                    else 'TOP30+' end)
```

Answer (score 0):

You use [CASE operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/flow-control-functions.html#operator_case)

> CASE *value*
>
> WHEN *compare_value* THEN *result*
>
> [WHEN *compare_value* THEN *result* ...]
>
> [ELSE *result*]
>
> END

So `ranking <= 11` is treated as an *compare_value* expression which' value must be calculated and compared with `ranking` *value*.

For `ranking = 1` the value for `ranking <= 11` is 1, i.e. equal to *value*, and `'Top10'` is returned.

For all another `ranking` values both *compare_value* are 1 or 0 or NULL and does not match *value*. So ELSE is selected.